# How to apply client side validation for input field in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `Jquery datatable` and I am storing input field. I want to apply client side validation on this input field.

```
{
   oTable.fnAddData([ '<input id="HoursDayWork' + i + '" 
                       class="form-control" value="0"  
                       onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" >']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate the input field allowing only numeric values then here is the code snippet

```
 function isNumberKey(e) {
        var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode <= 45 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```